# How do I make an armature skeleton?

Tags: rigging, armature

I am very new to Blender, so please forgive how simple this sounds and is. I am working on a spoof of VeggieTales, and I have a character who is pretty much a capsule, and I want to be able to bend him somewhere near his middle. I thought trying to create an armature in three segments (3 bones) would work for animating him, but I don't know how to connect the bones to each other. Can anyone help with this?

I've tried to connect them by making one a parent of the other, but any time I go into "Pose Mode", and try to rotate them, they simply come apart - as you can see.

[image]

Basically, I want the bones to stay together at the joints, and if the one at the bottom moves, then so do all the rest, etc.
Thank you for any help you can give!!

Comment: Despite my first instincts, in which I would have to refer you to the docs and mark this question for closure, I think you have a kernel of a legitimate question in there.  It seems like that question is something along the lines of "Why are my child bones not connecting/following to their parents?"  If this is true, please edit your question with some screenshots descriptions and we will better be able to help you.

Comment: hard to tell, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

After selecting your armature, go into edit mode and select **the bone you want to join** to your master bone (in your case, the lowest is your master bone). While in edit mode, go to:

`Properties >> Bone >> Relations`

and under "Parent", select the master bone and tick the "Connected" box. If you haven't named your bones, you might have to try all of them but luckily you've only got 3.